# Vídeos incorporados de forma responsiva

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, youtube

Bom dia, eu estou desenvolvendo um site e através dele você pode incorporar vídeos tanto do YouTube quanto do Facebook. Os vídeos do Youtube se adaptam perfeitamente conforme o tamanho da div, o problema está mesmo nos do Facebook no qual surgem quebrados se a sua altura fica maior ou menor que 300 pixels e sua largura for modificada.
Eis um esboço de meu código:

**CSS:**

```
/* css video incorporado */
.embedresize {
max-width: 560px;
margin: auto;
}

.embedresize div {
position: relative;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.embedresize iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.intro #intro .embedresize iframe,
.exit .quizz .embedresize iframe,
.alreadyplayed #intro .embedresize iframe,
.identityset #intro .embedresize iframe,
#notabene .embedresize iframe,
#message_intro .embedresize iframe,
.fancybox_body .embedresize iframe,
#comments .embedresize iframe,
#description .embedresize iframe,
.alreadyplayed .embedresize iframe,
#adserver .embedresize iframe {
max-width: none !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1 style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 14px; text-align: center;">Previa:</h1>
<div class="embedresize">
    <div>
       <iframe src="<?=$row_rsRegistro['vid_iframe'];?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true" height="300"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eis como o vídeo incorporado fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este código de HTML e CSS peguei de uns tutoriais gringos de como deixar o vídeo incorporado do Facebook em qualquer site.É possível você deixar este vídeo responsivo sem o uso de API's ou usar diferentes estruturas com confirmação de Back End?

Comment: Tente colocando `height:auto !important; max-height:300px !important; ` no CSS para ver se surte algum efeito... E tire o valor de altura do iframe

Comment: Alex uma coisa que percebi agora. Vc tem ideia do que seja esse **padding** no seu código? `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` ?

Comment: Como falei este CSS é de uns tutoriais gringos que dizem colocar isso aí nos sites deles e a responsividade funcionar normal.

Comment: Esse padding é para manter uma proporção de "aspect ratio" serve para deixar a proporção altura x largura com um valor definido independente do tamanho da tela. Vc pode ler sobre isso aqui! https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ Veja que com esse padding ai vc define a Div como a proporção 9/16 *" Now imagine instead of 100% top padding, we used 56.25%. That happens to be a perfect 16:9 ratio! (9 / 16 = 0.5625). "* Por isso que corta o vídeo. Pq ele vem talvez no formato 4:3... tira a altura e o padding do container pra ver o que acontece... limite o tamanho na largura talvez. boa leitura

Comment: O vídeo "desaparece", estou desenvolvendo usando o Bootstrap 3.3, tentei usar também as classes embed-responsive mas o resultado é o mesmo.